# Is date month in date range

Tags: c#, date

I have 2 date ranges as follows:

> Range 1: fromDate = 12/27/2015 toDate = 02/10/2016
>
> Range 2: startOfMonth = 01/01/2016 endOfMonth = 01/31/2016

What I am trying to do is return a boolean (true) if the from/to date range is in the range startMonth / endMonth, even if it's just 1 day. I display 1 month at a time so in my example this would return true if I select Dec 15, Jan 16 or Feb 16.

The from/to date range could be overlapping months, a few days within the month or just a single day in the month. If the date is in the startMonth-endMonth range then I simply want to return a boolean. I've tried various date comparison operations but can't seem to get this to work properly due to having 2 date ranges that evaluate based on the selected month.

What i have working so far is the following which almost does what I need but does not cover Range 1 above. Feb 16 does not return as valid.

```
if ((monthStart >= fromDate && monthEnd <= toDate) || (monthStart <= fromDate && monthEnd >= toDate))
```

Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: can you post code to show what you are actually doing..? this is not enough information to go by

Answer (score 0):

Why not just check:

```
if(startOfMonth >= fromDate  && endOfMonth <= toDate) { /* ... */ } else { /* ... */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got this working using the following logic.

```
if ((fromDate <= monthEnd) && (toDate >= monthStart)
{
    return true;
}
```

The ranges are now being shown correctly. In my example range

> fromDate = 12/27/2015
>
> toDate = 02/10/2016

I receive a true response for Dec 15, Jan 16 and Feb 16.